# Why is "Save and copy changes to all public communities" not copying GitHub and Twitter usernames?

Tags: bug, profile-page, profile-edit

I experienced this bug after creating profiles in a few Stack Exchange communities, editing my Stack Overflow profile and synching the information to all other communities using <kbd>Save and copy changes to all public communities</kbd>.

The profile picture and bio along with the personal website link were copied, but the fields 'Twitter link or username' and 'GitHub link or username' remained empty on all other community profiles.

I've read about problems affecting the profile picture and location, but I haven't found questions regarding GitHub and Twitter.

Is this a known bug? Is anyone else experiencing this?